# How to use mod_rewrite in Apache2?

Tags: mod-rewrite, ubuntu, apache2

I´m trying to do a simple redirection with Apache2 with mod_rewrite. I've installed the module in my Apache and I´ve set a webpage in localhost/file1/file2/page.html. I´m writing this in my 000-default file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule elegantdirectory/page.html file1/file2/page.html [L,NC]
```

So now if I try to access to localhost/elegantdirectory/page.html, the server is supposed to show me the page.html I have in file1/file2. Any ideas why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including bounds and a leading slash in your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^/elegantdirectory/page.html$ /file1/file2/page.html [L,NC]
```